# getting no mountable file systems error when trying to install android studio on mac

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, java-8

I've installed JDK 8 on my mac, but cannot install Android Studio, I get the error "no mountable file systems". However, Eclipse is working fine, any idea what the issue is? I also tried installing IDK 7 to see if Android Studio preferred that, but when I type java -version into the terminal it still says JDK 8 is running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue earlier today, the issue often indicates a corrupted dmg file. for me it turned out that downloading the dmg in chrome would always cause it to error, downloading it in safari worked fine.